# What's the name of this component (Mechanical Switch?)

Tags: components, identification

I am searching for the name of this electronic component (and a place to buy it):
[image: Mechanical switch]

It is some kind of mechanical switch.
When nothing pushes against the platic triangle, the switch is closed.

I have a couple of toy guns with this component, and this component always breaks.
(The part with the plastic triangle breaks off).
I want to replace it and fix the gun.

Comment: If it "always breaks" wouldn't it make sense to engineer a better solution rather than having to "always" replace it?

Comment: A general term for a switch operated by things, rather than people, is a limit switch, or "microswitch" (a trademark gone generic...).  However, I don't think I've ever seen one with contacts in the open like that.

Comment: @PeterBennett - if he could adapt an off-the-shelf microswitch to work for his device, it would probably last forever, or at least much longer than this open-contact switch.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very cheap and unreliable version of what's commonly named **microswitch**. It's unreliable because the two flimsy parts which make up the contacts are unprotected and, well, flimsy. I would suggest you replace it with a *real* microswitch like

[image]

The three solder contacts show that they're changeover contacts: one common, one normally open, and one normally closed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mechanical switch, and you can probably replace it with [this](http://ciiva.com/CloudSearch/Component/9193435/molex-waldom-cherry-dc2abwaa) one.